# Succulents that are heat tolerant and frost hardy

Tags: plant-recommendations, succulents

I wanna create a low maintenace succulent border that's  6ft by 6ft with plants that are both heat and frost tolerant but so far, everything that I've come across either cant stand the full sun or would die in the winters. I have this varigated agave (1st photo) that i wanna use as the center piece and have other succulents planted all around. I had bought alot of kolanchoes for the purpose but only to find out later that they arnt hardy enough. Recently, i had bought these (2nd photo) and would like to know if weather any of these would work since i have no experience with succulents apart from the one with the dark foliage. I had it outside all winter and it did very well.
I have a semi arid climate where summers are hot and dry and winters are cold and really wet.[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Bamboo's answer, there are literally a ton of sedum species and cultivars that would work for you (again, you need excellent drainage for most of them). Any of the Sedum spectabile or Sedum telephium cultivars would give you some height, while others (Sedum acre, Sedum kamschaticum, etc) would give you ground coverage. There are also "mid-size" varieties. Additionally, there are a few [cactus](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/garden-how-to/gardening-by-zone/zone-5/zone-5-cactus-plants.htm) hardy to US Zone 5, which might meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind low growing succulents, then Sempervivum varieties will fit the bill in terms of sun exposure and cold in winter. The only problem with many succulents is, they do not like winter wet, so I'm not sure how viable using succulents will be if your winters are very wet. https://homeguides.sfgate.com/care-instructions-sempervivum-38113.html